# ipywidget Text input and ipysheet interacting + voila

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I would like to get in jupyter the input text from a user.
Such input is supposed to be a csv, comma separated values.

Depending on that values I would like to generatate an interactive ipysheet which dependens on another dataframe data and the user input.

So:
a) user input.
b) ipysheet = f(user input)  filtering df
c) Final result = f(ipysheet)

Already in the first two steps I can not manage to get the thing working.

```
from ipysheet import from_dataframe, to_dataframe
from ipywidgets import *
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
csv = ipywidgets.Text(value='',
                         placeholder = 'type here',
                         description = 'csv:',
                         disabled    = False)


def submit(user_input):
    list=user_input.split(',')
    # here do calculations extracting data from df
    for i,word in enumerate(list):
        print(i,word)
    # if I would get this running here I would create the ipysheet like so:
    sheet = from_dataframe(df)



display(csv)
widgets.interact(submit,user_input=csv)
```

First: I am not able to link the text input and the submit fuction

Second: in submit function the only way to access df is with global df?

Third is it possible to link two ipysheets.

Comment: ipysheets are not getting rendered in voila. Is that the same issue you are facing. Did it get fixxed?